# Trouble passing data from if and if else

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a simple tic tac toe program as part of some homework but having difficulty in checking whether or not the game has been won. As soon as I launch the program and enter a number, it straight away says "Player 2 wins!" and I can't see what I have done wrong.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "tictactoe.h"

using namespace std;

void clearBoard(char gameBoard[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < board_size; i++)
    {
        gameBoard[i] = free_char;
    }
}

void printBoard(char gameBoard[])
{
    system("cls");

    //for (int i = 0; i < board_width; i++)
    //{
        //cout << gameBoard[i] + 1 << " " << gameBoard[i] + 1 << " " << gameBoard[i] + 1 << endl;
    //}

    cout << gameBoard[0] << " " << gameBoard[1] << " " << gameBoard[2] << endl;
    cout << gameBoard[3] << " " << gameBoard[4] << " " << gameBoard[5] << endl;
    cout << gameBoard[6] << " " << gameBoard[7] << " " << gameBoard[8] << endl;
}

int askMove(int player)
{
    cout << "Player " << player << ", Select a square [1-9]: ";
    cin >> choice;

    return 0;
}

bool verifyMakeMove(char gameBoard[], int move, int player)
{
    if (player == 1)
    {
        mark = p1_char;
    }
    else
    {
        mark = p2_char;
    }

    if (move < 1 || move > 9)
    {
        cout << "You did not enter a number between 1 and 9. Try again." << endl;
    }

    if (move == 1 && gameBoard[0] == free_char)
    {
        gameBoard[0] = mark;
    }
    else if (move == 2 && gameBoard[1] == free_char)
    {
        gameBoard[1] = mark;
    }
    else if (move == 3 && gameBoard[2] == free_char)
    {
        gameBoard[2] = mark;
    }
    else if (move == 4 && gameBoard[3] == free_char)
    {
        gameBoard[3] = mark;
    }
    else if (move == 5 && gameBoard[4] == free_char)
    {
        gameBoard[4] = mark;
    }
    else if (move == 6 && gameBoard[5] == free_char)
    {
        gameBoard[5] = mark;
    }
    else if (move == 7 && gameBoard[6] == free_char)
    {
        gameBoard[6] = mark;
    }
    else if (move == 8 && gameBoard[7] == free_char)
    {
        gameBoard[7] = mark;
    }
    else if (move == 9 && gameBoard[8] == free_char)
    {
        gameBoard[8] = mark;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "That move cannot be made. Try again." << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

int checkEndGame(char gameBoard[])
{
    if (gameBoard[0] == gameBoard[1] && gameBoard[1] == gameBoard[2])
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (gameBoard[3] == gameBoard[4] && gameBoard[4] == gameBoard[5])
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (gameBoard[6] == gameBoard[7] && gameBoard[7] == gameBoard[8])
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (gameBoard[0] == gameBoard[3] && gameBoard[3] == gameBoard[6])
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (gameBoard[1] == gameBoard[4] && gameBoard[4] == gameBoard[7])
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (gameBoard[2] == gameBoard[5] && gameBoard[5] == gameBoard[8])
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (gameBoard[0] == gameBoard[4] && gameBoard[4] == gameBoard[8])
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (gameBoard[2] == gameBoard[4] && gameBoard[4] == gameBoard[6])
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (gameBoard[0] != free_char && gameBoard[1] != free_char && gameBoard[2] != free_char && gameBoard[3] != free_char && gameBoard[4] != free_char && gameBoard[5] != free_char && gameBoard[6] != free_char && gameBoard[7] != free_char && gameBoard[8] != free_char)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

int playGame()
{
    char gameBoard[10];

    int player = 1;

    int winner;

    clearBoard(gameBoard);

    do
    {
    printBoard(gameBoard);

    askMove(player);

    verifyMakeMove(gameBoard, choice, player);

    checkEndGame(gameBoard);

    if (player == 1)
    {
        player = 2;
    }
    else
    {
        player = 1;
    }
    } while (checkEndGame(gameBoard) == 0);

    if (checkEndGame(gameBoard) == 1)
    {
        cout << "Player " << player << " wins!" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "It's a draw!" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    playGame();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you walked through the code with a debugger?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean. I'm using VS 2012 and running the debugger via ctrl+f5.

Comment: Haven't looked closely enough to be certain, but it probably thinks the game has been won by `free_char`. I.e. you don't check if there is a line of `mark`s, but a line of anything. And of course the board starts full of `free_char`s.

Comment: @cvandal It will save you **lots** of time in the long run if you become 100% sure what that means.  Look into using debugging controls in VS2012.  Then you can run your program one line at a time and see what's changing.

Comment: can you put the header too? so that we can test it.

Comment: Thank you Drew, I certainly will look into it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the start of the game, the board is blank. All nine squares have the same value, so they are all equal to each other. In particular, all three squares of some row are equal, so according to your logic, someone has won the game. You need to add additional logic to avoid that conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious problem is that in `checkEndGame`, you aren't checking for empty squares when you look for a line of three. The tests should be more like

```
if (gameBoard[0] != 0 && gameBoard[0] == gameBoard[1] && gameBoard[1] == gameBoard[2])
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

There are probably other problems, which you can find by stepping through the code with a debugger.